# click events on the fixed header

Tags: jquery, fixed-header-tables

I have used fixed header from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3819758) in my code. 
I want to be able to click the header columns and sort the table based on which column header is clicked. But I cannot get hold of the click event on the the column.

Comment: try this one is this you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/NWV73/23/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
$('.fixed-table').on('click', '.header-fixed th', function(){
    var th=$(this).index();
    alert('Column number is : ' + th + ' and text is : ' + $(this).text());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NWV73/27/).